# How to get EKF readings from Pixhawk using mavros pkg?

Tags: ros, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to get the EKF readings from pixhawk and there isn't any topic that can do that. I've tried using the '/mavros/local_position/local, pose, odom' and those readings are not satisfactory (Lot of jumps). Can anyone tell me how to resolve that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255343/how-to-get-ekf-readings-from-pixhawk-using-mavros-pkg?/) by [muralivnv](https://answers.ros.org/users/29454/muralivnv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the `/mavros/local_position/local, pose, odom` topics are in fact outputs of the EKF from PX4, fi they are jumpy then that would be an issue with the EKF, not with MAVROS. All MAVROS does is translate marlink messages into ROS messages, and if you look into the PX4 firmware you will see that the LOCAL_POSITION_NED mavlink message, which is what MAVROS is translating, is a direct output of the EKF urob topic.

If the problem is instead that you want a continuous stream of messages with no stutter then you can directly access the internal mavlink messages of the flight controller via a usb cord.

---

Originally posted by [eric1221bday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30851/eric1221bday/) with karma: 245 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0